# Is there a way to prevent machine from becoming unresponsive when amount of memory approaches 0?

Tags: linux, memory

I am running my machine from memory, and after heavily tasking it, it will become unresponsive until a significant amount of memory is freed up.

My machine has 16GB, my image is about 3.5GB, and I run intellij, maven, etc.  I still cannot imagine that I'm approaching 12GB or more, let alone 16GB.  If I am getting close to that situation, I would prefer to get an error saying, cannot allocate memory rather than have it become unresponsive.

My memory settings:

```
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0

vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
vm.overcommit_ratio = 100

vm.swappiness = 60
```

The only errors I am getting while simulating this problem are:

```
[Wed Nov  1 21:47:47 2017] wlan0: failed to remove key (1, 

ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
[Wed Nov  1 21:47:47 2017] wlan0: failed to remove key (2, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-22)
[Wed Nov  1 21:50:26 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13086] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 is taking a long time
[Wed Nov  1 21:51:54 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13086] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 timeout; kill it
[Wed Nov  1 21:51:54 2017] udevd[3187]: seq 2620 '/devices/platform/regulatory.0' killed
[Wed Nov  1 21:52:27 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13086] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[Wed Nov  1 21:52:27 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13086] failed while handling '/devices/platform/regulatory.0'
[Wed Nov  1 21:52:32 2017] crond (13080) used greatest stack depth: 12120 bytes left
[Wed Nov  1 21:54:12 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13099] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 is taking a long time
[Wed Nov  1 21:55:55 2017] udevd[13099]: timeout '/usr/sbin/crda'
[Wed Nov  1 21:55:55 2017] udevd[13099]: slow: '/usr/sbin/crda' [13101]
[Wed Nov  1 21:55:55 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13099] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 timeout; kill it
[Wed Nov  1 21:55:55 2017] udevd[3187]: seq 2621 '/devices/platform/regulatory.0' killed
[Wed Nov  1 21:57:03 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13099] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[Wed Nov  1 21:57:03 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13099] failed while handling '/devices/platform/regulatory.0'
[Wed Nov  1 21:59:01 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13118] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 is taking a long time
[Wed Nov  1 22:00:48 2017] udevd[13118]: timeout '/usr/sbin/crda'
[Wed Nov  1 22:00:57 2017] udevd[13118]: slow: '/usr/sbin/crda' [13122]
[Wed Nov  1 22:00:57 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13118] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 timeout; kill it
[Wed Nov  1 22:00:57 2017] udevd[3187]: seq 2622 '/devices/platform/regulatory.0' killed
[Wed Nov  1 22:01:35 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13118] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[Wed Nov  1 22:01:46 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13118] failed while handling '/devices/platform/regulatory.0'
[Wed Nov  1 22:03:40 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13140] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 is taking a long time
[Wed Nov  1 22:05:49 2017] udevd[13140]: timeout '/usr/sbin/crda'
[Wed Nov  1 22:05:54 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13140] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 timeout; kill it
[Wed Nov  1 22:05:54 2017] udevd[3187]: seq 2623 '/devices/platform/regulatory.0' killed
[Wed Nov  1 22:06:03 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13140] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[Wed Nov  1 22:06:03 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13140] failed while handling '/devices/platform/regulatory.0'
[Wed Nov  1 22:08:00 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13164] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 is taking a long time
[Wed Nov  1 22:09:50 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13164] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 timeout; kill it
[Wed Nov  1 22:09:50 2017] udevd[3187]: seq 2624 '/devices/platform/regulatory.0' killed
[Wed Nov  1 22:09:50 2017] crda (13170) used greatest stack depth: 12104 bytes left
[Wed Nov  1 22:10:08 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13164] terminated by signal 9 (Killed)
[Wed Nov  1 22:10:21 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13164] failed while handling '/devices/platform/regulatory.0'
[Wed Nov  1 22:11:49 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13180] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 is taking a long time
[Wed Nov  1 22:13:57 2017] udevd[3187]: worker [13180] /devices/platform/regulatory.0 timeout; kill it
[Wed Nov  1 22:13:57 2017] udevd[3187]: seq 2625 '/devices/platform/regulatory.0' killed
```

Comment: Isn't there anything on dmesg when that happens?

Comment: So, it sounds like what you want is something that will prevent you from starting new applications, if your memory usage is over a certain threshold (say 12GB out of 16GB)?

Comment: @Time4Tea - Right

Comment: @Zip - I remoted into a machine, then filled up memory using dd while monitoring dmesg and tailing the logs in another console.  I didn't see any error messages whatsoever, while the machine became (and is) unresponsive.  I expect to see some kernel messages, but see nothing.  I can see the system is still running as NetworkManager is printing logs.  The test machine has 8GB of memory and I filled over 4GB of it with a random file.  This machine is not running from memory, so it would ave 4GB roughly for i3, intellij, and the background processes.

Comment: Cpu usage percentages? Swap usage? Chances are something is getting exhausted and you need to identify which process/operation is causing it.

Comment: I have no swap, just memory.  I am guessing that the system is stuck because it is waiting for a task to complete, but it cannot complete because it is waiting for memory to allocate?

Comment: I monitored this on another machine that has less ram and am able to reproduce this fairly easily.  When I am running chrome with several tabs open or am editing a few photos at the same time, I can reproduce the hang every time.  It appears that the disk IO jumps to about 20MB/s for disk read at the time the hang occurs while I still have about 3GB free of 8GB ram.  I don't see anything in dmesg reporting any errors.  It still doesn't make sense to me why the machine would hang like it does, slow, yes.